# rescue_from doesn't catch an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_data, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_data
  respond_to :html

  def show
   respond_with(@item)
  end

  private

  def set_data
    @item = Item.find params[:id]
  end


  def invalid_data
    logger.log "Error, id: #{params[:id]}"
    redirect_to some_url, error: 'Error123'
  end

end
```

Still, when I go to `my/123` or `my/123fdsfds` or `my/fdsfds`, I get a standard "error" screen:

```
ArgumentError in MyController#show
comparison of String with 0 failed

    logger.log "Error, id: #{params[:id]}"
    redirect_to some_url, error: 'Error123'
  end
end
```

and I don't get redirected. How come?

Comment: Does your 'standard error screen' just have the first two lines of that second code block or the whole thing?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you screenshot your error screen you're receiving? I'm checking your controller and I can't seem to find the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out, looger.log itself caused the error, it should be:

```
logger.log Logger::ERROR, "Error, id: #{params[:id]}"
```